# Is there any way to gain "truth"/accuracy in social truth? How?

Tags: truth, social-ethics

Is there any way to gain "truth"/accuracy in social truth? How?

What seems to make it difficult is that I don't know if social truth has any generally accepted epistemologies, truth deduction principles, consistency etc. Thus it makes it too easy to treat the entirety of "social truth" as "subjective opinion" from which it's always possible to deviate. And then one loses possibly all accuracy, because, in theory, every subject could deviate from whatever claim.

Input?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean "Is there anyway to obtain knowledge in social sciences?"

Comment: @JishinNoben Not that broadly. More like, when can one permit reasoning in "vague" domains, such as social truth? E.g. if one proposes a claim in social truth, then how can one decide on whether or not one should agree on it? Based on something else than subjectivity.

Comment: The only quantifiable would the ballot boxes, maybe precedent law, and voting with wallets i.e. commercial popularity.

Comment: @christo183 For example. Which at least drove me to minarchism. There's possible not much in modern politics, which has any well-known "accuracy". More like subjective belief applied globally. Which makes the context of politics for example seem absurdly naive.

Comment: @Gordon No they're not the same. E.g. reasoning is a process, whereas intuition could be regarded as more immediate. Premises are again either intuitive or reasoned. There are different time scales, different variations of subjective-objective etc. My questions differ in "context".

Comment: You need to read everything, believe nothing, and make up your own mind.

Comment: @user4894 I don't see how that works for social animals though. There must be some way to connect with others. It's not enough that I can make up my own mind, others need too. And in order to avoid conflict, they'd need to be same.

Comment: @mavavilj Why must there be conflict because people have different opinions? You can agree to disagree, can't you? You really believe everyone must have the same opinion on everything and that there's no way to avoid conflict with people whose opinion differs from yours? I gather this is a popular belief these days but it couldn't be more wrong.

Comment: @user4894 One could perceive that "competitors" be abolished. And act on that will. So there must not, but it's "as probable" as there being. And as an "undecideable" context, both and all actions ought to be permittable, because there's no way to conclude any way. This is the contrary of e.g. political decision-making, which is de facto authoritarian and often pseudoscientific.

Comment: You should look at [Habermas's theory of communicative rationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicative_rationality), I think it was designed exactly with this concern in mind.

Comment: @Conifold Are you sure? I already disagree with  (2) moral-practical reason; and (3) aesthetic-expressive reason as being formal contexts. I would take only (1) and be with it.

Comment: Your question is about procedures for coming to a rational consensus in vague domain, e.g. to "transform implicit "know-how" into explicit "know-that"".  Which principles you agree or disagree with, or which know-how specifically you wish to transform, is beside the point.

Comment: @Conifold Why is rational consensus an appropriate measurement for accuracy? Why is not the decision of the strongest an appropriate measurement?

Comment: You'll have to read Habermas to find out.

Comment: One way rational consensus may work is through the aforementioned "commercial popularity". An example would be a review website where hundreds of users give feedback on their experience with a product. The variety and number of reports can then become a statistically significant measure.

Comment: @christo183 Except if the majority pattern is based on non-well-informed judgements. See Betamax vs VHS.

Comment: Of course, and in the example all the care of applying statistics in general should be kept in mind. I.e. if I want to use my product in the desert it won't help if all previous reviews came from Europe. It gets worse when, like in politics, certain parties have a vested interest in promoting a particular perception... The problems in extracting objective measures from subjective sampling is great, but not in principal insurmountable.

Answer (score 1):

Upon pondering this question a bit. I would (informedly) answer that, yes there is in some sense.

The some sense is *agreement* or *disagreement*. Everything beyond this steps into much more noticeable subjectivity. Also, without agreement or disagreement I don't think one could have any expression and "silence" would not work for social animals for practical reasons. Thus in "Occam's razoric sense" one's left with "minimal premises" to decide on something.

However, this has a vague concept of accuracy, since the only unambiguously measurable is the count of *agreement* or the count of *disagreement*. Still it's entirely possible that 1) the question to be answered has been formulated in a bad way and 2) people passing the vote are not *well-informed*. Thus e.g. democracies don't really guarantee for anything. They act on much arbitrarity.

Thus I'm not sure how this answers the problem of "accuracy", because it relies on arbitrary notions of accuracy. Theoretically one could expect accuracy if one relied only on "well-informed" voters, but I'm not sure how one'd formulate criteria for being well-informed (I don't claim it to be impossible though). Relying on merely count, while being absolute, would not work for *accuracy*.

Thus I think that social truth may build upon some of the following:

- Demonstrated experience (replicability)
- Being able to be proven wrong with new evidence / anti-authoritarianism (fallibility)
- Relying on well-defined terms (*operational definitions*)
- Understanding of mathematical, physical truth and related science epistemologies, since they represent the best model for all knowledge (formality, consistency)

I would also add that since there are things that will not fit to these, then these would be perhaps categorizable as *undecidable*. Particularly, because without having accuracy, it would be dumb to suggest either *agreement* or *disagreement* because one cannot demonstrate anything either way. Thus it should be left as *undecideable*. *Undecideable* means that it cannot be decided either way, it can be (in order to allow distinguishing natural separation of thought from action) merely acted on "somehow", and this action is "non-determinable".

Comment: Also perhaps, add *consistency in action*. That means that if one holds a particular rule as being "applicable". Then whenever confronted with the same context, that rule must hold. Otherwise one could not decide, when it holds and when it doens't. And then "rule" would make no sense.